# BootStrap - Model Binding and HTML5/CSS3 support?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

Does Bootstrap provide model binding, validation or is it just a bunch of pretty styles?  Would I have to use something like knockout.js to using binding?

I'm planning on using it for website that displays analytic data, charts, KPI's etc, and I really like the styles (plan on using high charts for charting).

Also, does Bootstrap:

- Support HTML5 or CSS3?
- Seamless views for mobile/tablet/web (where I don't have to write a template for each endpoint?)

Comment: Did you were here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap is basically a set of CSS (rather LESS) styles and javascript widgets.  It does not provide model bindings.  You can find libraries that allow you to access Bootstrap functionality through binding handlers (e.g., Knockout-Bootstrap) or html directives (e.g., AngularStrap).

Bootstrap is more than "pretty styles," but it isn't in the same category as a model binding or validation framework.  If you're looking for Javascript frameworks, these are popular: Angular (from Google), Knockout, Meteor (cutting-edge), and Backbone (simple, lightweight).

If you want to use Bootstrap with a front-end JS framework, you could try Yeoman, which has generators that scaffold this stuff for you -- including one that provides Bootstrap (or Boostrap w/ Compass) with Angular or Backbone.

Yes, Bootstrap uses CSS3 with graceful fallback, as does Compass (you can use both of them at the same time even).  You'll have to design in responsive features using bootstrap-responsive.css (look at their online documentation).  If you want something more out of the box for "seamless views," you can try WrapBootstrap for pre-built themes.

Hope this gives you an idea of the landscape you're considering.

Comment: awesome!  Very, very helpful!